# Query to find out day of each of employees date of birth

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I tried this code.But Its not working.(I am using NetBeans Internal database)

Code is-

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,DOB) AS BirthYear,
DATEPART(mm,DOB) AS BirthMonth,
DATEPART(dd,DOB) AS BirthDay
FROM Employees
WHERE EmpId=1
```

> Error-
>
> [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X04] Column 'YYYY' is either
>   not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join
>   specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or
>   appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is
>   a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'DD' is not a column in the
>   target table.

Comment: which db you are using  ?

Comment: I am using mysql.

Comment: I have already post and answer  ..mysql use specific function asyear(), month() and day() for retreive waht you are looking for a datetime column ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assumin DOB is valida date column if you are using mysql you should use year(), month() and day() and not datepart ..

```
SELECT year(DOB) AS BirthYear,
       month(DOB) AS BirthMonth,
        day(DOB) AS BirthDay
FROM Employees
WHERE EmpId=1
```

*(datepart if for sqlserver)*

and for each Employee you can

```
SELECT EmpId,
       year(DOB) AS BirthYear,
       month(DOB) AS BirthMonth,
        day(DOB) AS BirthDay
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL has functions for those, [see doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT
    YEAR(DOB)AS BirthYear,
    MONTH(DOB)AS BirthMonth,
    DAY(DOB)AS BirthDay
FROM
    Employees
WHERE
    EmpId = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL has a specialized function that returns the index of the Weekday. The documentation says:

```
DAYOFWEEK(date)

Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = 
Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.

mysql> SELECT DAYOFWEEK('2007-02-03');
    -> 7
```

So you could basically use it in your query and the manipulate the output based on the index later. Something like this:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(DOB) AS Day_of_Week,
FROM Employees
WHERE EmpId=1;
```

If you wish to get the output from the query itself, you can use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE DAYOFWEEK(DOB)
       WHEN 1 THEN 'SUNDAY'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'MONDAY'
       ---
    END AS Day_of_Week
FROM Employees
WHERE EmpId=1;
```

Hope it works!! Good Luck!